# XCode 4 IB: Can't see bounds or geometry. Dragging = Guessing

Tags: xcode4, interface-builder

I'm not sure what I did, but today I was unable to see the bounds of objects in Xcode 4.3.2.

Anyone know what's up? I'm not sure if I accidentally pressed a hotkey or something...I can resize things but I can't see the size or what I've selected. If I type in a static text field there's no text indicator. I type blindly and hit enter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently NSImageCells overlap all of the constraints. Just move it to the back of the hierarchy and everything should be fine.